# Programmatically invoke in Android 9 the QR code scanner system app

Tags: android, android-intent, barcode-scanner

Starting from Android 9 (API level 28) a new system app is available for scanning barcodes 1D/2D : its name is "**QT code scanner**".

Is there any **intent to call this system app** and have it handle barcode detection in live camera preview to just grab the decoded string in onActivityResult() when the app is done?

Thanks!

Comment: What is your evidence that this is on every single Android 9 and 10 device model?

Comment: Are these pages helpful? [Barcode API Overview](https://developers.google.com/vision/android/barcodes-overview), [Scan Barcodes with ML Kit on Android](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ml-kit/android/read-barcodes), [How to scan QR codes with Android phones without an app](https://blog.beaconstac.com/2019/03/how-to-scan-qr-codes-with-android-phones/)

Comment: @CommonsWare : acc! you are right! I was mislead by several announcements that, when properly inspected, revealed the feature is actually something provided by the System Camera that now integrates some ML algorithms and relies on an online service (Google Lens) to perform the actual decoding. Definitely something that cannot be invoked programmatically.

Comment: @kunif : I already went through those posts (or similar) by they all require to build a Camera preview in the app. There is no ready-to-use UI component in Play Services to perform barcode capture. That is the point. Handling reliably a live preview across the Android device universe is something I am willing to face. Definitely an offline barcode app would have been as useful as the Gmail app is for most users. I am wondering why it doesn't get shipped out of the box!